# Why must use different hash functions in partition and probe phase of Grace Hash Join?

Tags: algorithm, join, hash

Since there will be a modulo operation anyways, why do we need different hash functions?

Answer (score 0):

In the Grace join, both inputs are partitioned according to the first hash function, and then for each partition, a hash table is built.

If you you used the same hash function for both operations, then there would only be a relatively small number of possible hash values for the keys in each hash table, because each partition is restricted to a small number of those hash values.  This could lead to increased collisions and decreased efficiency.

Depending on the sizes of the input and the partitions, it wouldn't *always* be a problem, but a robust algorithm doesn't rely on receiving favourable inputs.